# Ethical violation in chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

### Background

So the relevant transcript starts here:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51655733#51655733

My summary of it goes like this:

1. There's a derivation I am not content with.
2. I [post a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/501145/validity-of-the-derivation-of-time-energy-uncertainty-principle) which gets down voted (regarding this derivation after 
   commenting on it and recieving no update).
3. Then I ask chat where I'm going wrong.
4. To be fair I probably wasn't using the best language to get my point across.
5. After some time Semiclassical and bolbteppa not making sense to me (and 
   visa-versa).
6. Acuiousmind joins and understands where I'm coming from.
7. It Semiclassical and Acuriousmind reach an understanding where I'm coming 
   from eventually. (In fact this whole thing makes semi-classical realise that 
   the physical situation he considers it is applicable is beyond it's scope).
8. Acuriousmind explains to me the scope of the applicability is less than what 
   I assume (and I agree).
9. However, Bolbteppa does not agree with any of this (infact my objection does 
   not make sense to him).
10. After speaking to Bolbteppa I realise he does not understand my objection 
    because of his views on the nuances of this topic.
11. Later on I understand his viewpoint may enable to circumvent my objection 
    and I ask a question on physics stack exchange on the same.
12. I ask several questions in attempts to clarify my understanding. In fact one in paticular if Bolbteppa can circumvent the objection.
13. But after a point acuriousmind seems to lose is initial patience and starts 
    typing stuff like.
    14:"Your "objection" is still non-sensical as I explained at length yesterday (the M-T time-energy relation has nothing to do with measurements happening) and I'm not going to repeat it."
14. I feel this mis-represents my view as my objection is about the scope of applicability of this derivation.
15. In fact, acuriousmind ends it with: "I won't pretend to speak for bolbteppa. I've said twice now (and also yesterday) that your objection is not, in my opinion, well-defined or meaningful. As you don't appear to be willing to hear that, I'm done with this conversation."

Anyway, I'm not trying to be thick I genuinely feel I'm trying to learn something.

Now, if any other user had mis-represented my objection and intentionally remained silent after that and also accused me of not listening. I would have let it go. I myself feel that I am not the ideal Stackexchange user. However, for Acuriousmind is a moderator so I'd like to hold him to a different standard (perhaps this is my folly).

### Question

Is there any course of action I can take to prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: To the downvoter: I hope you have read the entire (massive) transcript and then (responsibly) downvoted?

Comment: Yes, I read it all. I wish I could have those 20 minutes back. I do not see any ethical violation.

Comment: @G.Smith I see. In that case I must clearly be in the wrong as I'm also guessing you up-voted ACuriousMind

Comment: That’s correct, although it is really none of your business. As you know, no one has to explain their upvotes or downvotes.

Comment: Is this even worthy of a meta post? If I have a bad conversation with a user/users I just walk away and then forget about it in about a day.

Comment: @AaronStevens I hold a mod to a higher standard as mentioned. Otherwise, I would take your course of action.

Comment: I don't think there is a standard for moderators to understand everything you are trying to say though, is the thing.

Comment: The 3'rd comment to answer is what I feel is bothering me and below the standard

Comment: I was reading the chat when ACM made the final statement... it made perfect sense.  You were going in circles, and he wasn't going to speak for someone else to address the other part of what you asked him.  I don't think asking about "ethical violations", in this sense, really belongs on meta either.

Comment: @JMac I wish he just said "he wasn't going to speak for someone else to address the other part of what you asked him." Rather than saying "your objection is not, in my opinion, well-defined or meaningful." ... I feel both statements are worlds apart .. And am now under the opinion that Acuriousmind would disagree with you.

Comment: There are more than 1700 chat messages between the first message that you link and the message where you announced you were writing this meta. If you're looking at the desktop version of the chat transcript there is a "bookmark a conversation" button that lets you construct compact links to the parts of this long transcript which are important.  That would be helpful for those of us with less patience than @G.Smith.

Comment: Saying something is not well-defined or meaningful is not unethical

Comment: Yes, but forcing someone to play a guessing game on what you mean seems unethical to me ... I mean this why I'm telling JMac "Acuriousmind would disagree with you" because I have to guess Acuriousminds stance.

Comment: @MoreAnonymous Those statements are worlds apart... because they address different things.  You asked "_can I conclude bolbteppa does not circumvent my objection and does no better?_" and ACM responded "_I won't pretend to speak for bolbteppa. I've said twice now (and also yesterday) that your objection is not, in my opinion, well-defined or meaningful._" Those are two separate statements addressing different things.  The fact that ACM cannot speak about what bolbteppa does, and that ACM did not find the statement meaningful _in their opinion_.  Nothing is wrong with that. People have opinions

Comment: @MoreAnonymous If, on the other hand, you're done with this question, there's no reason to go through the effort of constructing the bookmarked conversation snippets. (I started to make one for you, but a bookmarked conversation can only be 400 messages long, and I wasn't participating in the chat and don't have the context to know what's important to you.)

Comment: @JMac when he says my objection is wrong I was of the opinion he was saying  I'm applying it to situations u can't (which I agreed to). Also bolbteppa circumvent's my objection by clearly applying it places I think he can't. So maybe I'm in the wrong for trying to guess why objection is wrong??   Plus during the whole conversation of Acuriousmind explaining all this to me ,,, there seems to be a silent agreement between him and bolbteppa .... How much of a guessing game am I supposed to playing here?

Comment: @rob to be fair since there are involved parties even my version of a personalised snippet would be wrong

Comment: @MoreAnonymous ... uh what?  I think you're reading a lot of subtext that isn't there.  ACM spent a long time trying to understand what you were saying and explain his own personal thoughts.  Everyone should have the right to leave a conversation like that in a chat room if they feel it's just circular.  I'm not sure why you're trying to paint anyone in the "wrong", not every conversion is productive, and sometimes you have to cut your losses.  Doesn't make anyone wrong.

Comment: @JMac I feel while ACM did make his point of view clear he did not make his point of view on bolbteppa's point of view clear ... I wish he had spelt it out ... To be fair bolbteppa was chiming in simultaneously and was and still is of the opinion whatever I was going on about was wrong and doesnt limit the scope of the derivation .... I can't see why he couldn't have ACM didn't make his views clear about this ... (unless he is in agreement and that should have been obvious to me)

Comment: @JMac I wrote this rob so I thought I'd write it personally to you as well: maybe if you or anyone in this meta post would be willing to clarify what is going on ... I would love to know exactly that ... Not as ACM's line of argument but as your own. I would be more than delighted to converse ... Anyway even if you say yes .. It can't be tonight since I need to catch up on sleep and my mental fatigue will work against me ... Cheers!

Comment: @MoreAnonymous If you want help with the physics part of your discussion, you should ask a question on the main site rather than trying to have that discussion in meta comments. If you've already asked a physics question, a link to it in your meta question would be appropriate. If you want to know how one user would summarize another user's understanding of your physics question you should ... not do that. We're just not a good forum for those kinds of speculation.

Comment: @rob I changed the link you edited maybe I misunderstood you when you said "If you've already asked a physics question" ... I was thinking of a question which would answer the conundrum which is this one: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/502221/does-the-copenhagen-interpretation-allow-one-to-bypass-a-derivations-objection

Comment: @rob I edited the link above (this comment) because accidently I used the wrong one

Comment: feel that sometimes the chat room regulars, some of them with high status, routinely put words in other ppls mouths, sometimes based on "official" examples. as for *unethical* no. but yes, sometimes users are *unwelcoming* or *impatient* around here. your other challenge is that youre interested in QM interpretations and thats a low-status subject around here, and theres not much interest in anything but Copenhagen aka **the party line** aka **groupthink**. there are new experiments directly challenging it but theres very little )( awareness or discussion on this around these parts. _caveat!_

Comment: @vzn There is much discussion on this site that looks at interpretations besides Copenhagen. You might be confused because many questions that do ask about the deeper concepts of QM interpretations tend to be poor questions that are either really unclear or are very speculative and blatently off-topic. But you can find many questions and discussions here about QM interpretations.

Comment: @rob I feel if multiple users can only speculate what acm meant despite the time and text written... Then that is definitely part of the problem.

Comment: I have read most of the transcript, although I must admit that many of your chat posts are hard for me to read, due to frequent spelling errors, duplicated words, non-standard abbreviations (eg "shd") and similar grammatical issues. But IMHO ACuriousMind has *not* back-tracked or back-flipped.

Comment: @pm2ring acm does voice a similar concern (towards the end) of me being over condensed. However if that is the problem I would have loved if someone had said so earlier. In fact if the real problem is terrible Internet lingo maybe we should add a minimal language quality in the chat for serious topics?

Comment: In [this post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=51658546#51658546) ACM says "I have explained why I think your question is problematic even if your underlying confusion is earnest and legitimate, and I have explained why I think josh's answer is a good answer to the question it is written as an answer to". He agrees that the topic can be confusing, especially to newcomer, but he doesn't agree with your objection, to the extent that he actually understands your objection.

Comment: @pm2ring also I feel this English problem is quite prevelant in my country. We reduce the number of words under the assumption of understood context. In fact I only realised this miscommunication problem when my international friends pointed it out and I was like this never happens to me in my country.

Comment: Chat is just chat, and people like being able to chat informally, and not spend energy being as careful with what they say as they (presumably) do on the main site. OTOH, yes, we do need to ensure that we express ourselves with adequate clarity when discussing advanced topics, otherwise misunderstandings are bound to occur.

Comment: @pm2ring I was obviously under the false impression acm meant that I was applying this derivation in cases I can't (to which I agreed). However I can definitely see someone make the case with bolbteppa version that someone could overlook my objection. And that is what I was later asking him. However if I misunderstood him in my first sentence it's not circular at all we never made any progress at all in my understanding.

Comment: Indian English is a legitimate form of English, but it does have several non-standard features that may not always be correctly understood by non-Indians. Some of those things, like the way Indians use "doubt" and "same", aren't too difficult, once we're familiar with them, but I'm sure there are plenty of other things that we simply don't notice which lead to misinterpretation and misunderstandings.

Comment: @PM2Ring I've massively edited the post (to make it self contained and my objection clear). Please let me know if anything is unclear?? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/502221/does-the-copenhagen-interpretation-allow-one-to-bypass-a-derivations-objection

Comment: It looks ok to me, but I don't have enough expertise in quantum physics to respond to it adequately.

Comment: I don't think this question makes it clear exactly what it is you're asking how to prevent. Also, I don't see anything in the question that identifies the possible ethical violation you're referring to in the title.

Comment: @davidz in this meta post to summarise my stance.. I was under the impression the ethical violation refers to misrepresenting my stance, remaining silent and accusing me of not listening. I am currently of the stance whatever acm was trying to tell me didn't indeed make sense to me. I do massively edit a question post linked above (in the comment section) comparing the 3rd and 4th way which is what I was trying to understand something.. But at this point I am of the view I am fundamentally misunderstanding something about qm. I don't think anything will come out of this meta here so I concede

Comment: @DavidZ I am also confused why this post is "on hold" I was of the opinion I accepted an answer even though perhaps not in the best of circumstances (however I was the opinion that was acceptable) ... I am even ending with the words "I concede" in the above comment so as to make my stance clear (for those who only see the last comment)... Maybe you can show me some meta guideline I am not aware of ??

Comment: If I may just randomly say: I read the whole chat transcript and actually found the whole conversation genuinely endearing. I especially loved the lad who kept bringing up different subjects in order to bring everyone together.

Comment: @WhitePrime who doesn't love that guy! I'd talk some fluid mechanics too but maybe not on meta. Also the "whole conversation" endearing? Was I even part of this "whole conversation"? :P

Comment: @MoreAnonymous (4 comments up) It sounds like you thought it would be obvious to readers of your question that the ethical violations you were referring to are misrepresenting your stance, remaining silent, and accusing you of not listening. That's not at all obvious. That's why I voted to put the question on hold. Editing the question to make it explicitly clear what you believe are the ethical violations would be a big step toward getting the hold removed.

Comment: @DavidZ Would it be okay just to delete it? (the whole post)

Comment: If the system gives you the option to delete it by displaying a "delete" link below the question, then you're free to use it if you want. Otherwise, just leave it in place.

Comment: @DavidZ "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Users (whether moderators or not) are free to disengage from any conversation - in chat or on the main site - whenever they like. You are not entitled to anyone's time on this platform (we're all here voluntarily!), and to suggest that it is "unethical" for someone to stop participating in a conversation they no longer deem useful or interesting is simply absurd.

Users are also free to be *wrong* - yes, even moderators! I may have misunderstood you, or you have misunderstood me, or both. This is unfortunate, but also not a moral failing (unless done with ill intent), nor something that can be avoided in all cases.

The only thing you can do to prevent other users from disengaging or misunderstanding is to express yourself as clearly as you can, and to listen to their criticisms of what you say as fairly as you can. It will still happen from time to time, and not always through any fault of your own.

Comment: I do also mention "accused me of not listening" and I could have also accused you of backtracking when you say "your objection is not, in my opinion, well-defined or meaningful." Your flip-flop stance on my objection seems to suggest that

Comment: @MoreAnonymous - disagreeing on interpretations of physics, and stopping to talk for whatever reason (hey, maybe work needs to get done) are not, and never have been ethical violations. Sure, you didn't like it, but that does not mean that others did anything unethical, illegal, immoral, or just wrong.

Comment: @JonCuster alright so (false)-accusations and backtracking (in an intellectual argument) are ethical as well?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous - Again, you did not like the chat. And you must be used to always being right in an intellectual discussion - good on you.

Comment: @JonCuster also this is not a disagreement on the interpretations of the physics. It's about with one interpretation if one can get more mileage (apply it in more physical situations)

Comment: @JonCuster I'm under the impression you feel Acuriousmind does not accuse me but points out a "fact" (which makes it okay) ... Also Acuriousmind does not backtrack which makes me completely convinced whatever his position is I don't get it. And no I have learned a lot from being wrong ... But I've also learned by asking questions

Comment: @MoreAnonymous - I see why people disengage in discussions with you.

Comment: @JonCuster maybe because I ask them to spell out their positions?

Comment: Alright I'm gonna accept this answer because I feel this will not go anymore. Clearly I am in the wrong (even though at the moment I dont think so).

Comment: @MoreAnonymous It takes a strong person to admit they are in the wrong before they completely understand why. We appreciate users who are willing to back out of heated discussions; sometimes just a little bit of time is all that's needed to bring clarity to a tense situation. Good on you.

Comment: @rob thank you ... I must say my experience on this site has been brilliant for me not leave it because of this one instance. Also about the bookmark comment has someone bookmarked it or were you asking me to bookmark it?

Comment: @rob maybe if you or anyone in this meta post would be willing to clarify what is going on ... I would love to know exactly that ... Not as ACM's line of argument but as your own. I would be more than delighted to converse ... Anyway even if you say yes .. It can't be tonight since I need to catch up on sleep and my mental fatigue will work against me ... Cheers!

Comment: @rob eh, I'm not so sure about the value of admitting you're wrong without understanding why. I'd frame it more as declining to continue a line of discussion that isn't productive. Though in this case it kind of works out to the same effect.

Comment: @DavidZ if it helps lemme say I was in the wrong and have apologised to ACM ...